# Trigger not working correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Im using the following bit of code in a trigger called on update, insert, delete.
Problem is when the trigger is run it updates all balance totals to be the the same in the invoice table.....It is supposed to update each invoice total based on the invoicelines sum() that correspond and NOT update them to be all the same. Ive been stuck with this for hours and just cant get my head around it.

```
UPDATE invoices
SET invoices.Amount = (SELECT
SUM(invoicelines.Amount) AS expr1
FROM invoicelines i
INNER JOIN invoicelines
ON i.Id = i.Id
WHERE i.InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId
GROUP BY i.InvoiceId) 
WHERE Id = Id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have the outer WHERE clause with:

```
WHERE id = NEW.id;
```

Otherwise you will update every record in the table, since every record will return true to the fact that their ID is equal to their ID.

Additionally, If you want to remove or add invoicelines amounts to the invoice amount, that is too much work.

You can just do:

**For INSERT**

```
UPDATE invoices
    SET Amount = Amount + NEW.amount
WHERE id = NEW.InvoiceId;
```

**For UPDATE:**

```
UPDATE invoices
    SET Amount = Amount + NEW.amount - OLD.amount
WHERE id = NEW.InvoiceId;
```

**For DELETE:**

```
UPDATE invoices
    SET Amount = Amount - OLD.amount
WHERE id = OLD.InvoiceId;
```

Comment: @user2917229 Does invoicelines table have Amount column?

Comment: Thank you BUDDY you are a STAR! Worked!

Comment: @user2917229. Glad it did. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. Check [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) for help on how to do that.

Comment: Based on your prior answer what what about this one?
      UPDATE customers
      SET Balance = Balance - (SELECT
      SUM(Amount)
      FROM payments p
      WHERE p.CustomerId = p.CustomerId)
      WHERE Id = Id;

Comment: You have to have something that makes it unique in your inner query, like ... `WHERE p.CustomerId = NEW.customerId) WHERE Id = NEW.customerID;`.

Comment: UPDATE customers
  SET Balance = Balance - (SELECT SUM(Amount) 
  FROM payments p 
  WHERE p.CustomerId = NEW.customerId) 
  WHERE Id = NEW.customerID;

Where did I go wrong on this, and will this work for update insert delete?

Comment: You really should open a different question for these unrelated subjects. But on that one, i think you need to remove the "Balance - ", since you are calculating the SUM

Comment: Just posted another one for you .... this will be the last one for the night.....